# Python getting exact cell from csv file

Tags: python, csv, cell

```
import csv

filename = str(input("Give the file name: "))
    file = open(filename, "r")
    with file as f:
        size = sum(1 for _ in f)

    print("File", filename, "has been read, and it has", size, "lines.", size - 1, "rows has been analyzed.")
```

I pretty much type the csv file path to analyze and do different things with it.

First question is: How can I print the exact cell from the CSV file? I have tried different methods, but I can't seem to get it working.
[image: For example I want to print the info of those two cells]

For example I want to print the info of those two cells

The other question is: Can I automate it to print the very first cell(1 A) and the very last row first cell (1099 A), without me needing to type the cell locations?

Thank you

Small portion of data

Example of the data:

```
Time    Solar Carport   Solar Fixed  SolarFlatroof  Solar Single
1.1.2016    317         1715         6548           2131
2.1.2016    6443        1223         1213           23121
3.1.2016    0           12213        0              122
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Are you aware of pandas library? That's well suited for this job. Do you like to explore that?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

Comment: Thanks both. I have indeed tried to look at both of those guides, but haven't really found the right loaction where it's explained.

Comment: Added a download link to the file
Added also a small text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You import `csv` at the very top but then decided not to use it. I wonder why – it seems *just* what you need here. So after a brief peek at [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), I got this:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('../Downloads/htviope2016.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in spamreader:
        data.append (row)

print("File has been read, and it has ", len(data), " lines.")
```

That is all you need to read in the entire file. You don't need to – for some operations, it is sufficient to process one line at a time – but with the full data loaded and ready in memory, you can play around with it.

```
print (f'First row length: {len(data[0])}')
```

The number of cells per row. Note that this first row contains the header, and you probably don't have any use for it. Let's ditch it.

```
print ('Discarding 1st row NOW. Please wait.')
data.pop(0)
```

Done. A plain `pop()` removes the last item but you can also use an index. Alternatively, you could use the more pythonic (because "slicing") `data = data[1:]` but I assume this could involve copying and moving around large amounts of data.

```
print ('First 10 rows are ...')
for i in range(10):
    print ('\t'.join(data[i])+'(end)')
```

Look, there is data in memory! I pasted on the `(end)` because of the following:

```
print (f'First row, first cell contains "{data[0][0]}"')
print (f'First row, last cell contains "{data[0][-1]}"')
```

which shows

```
First row, first cell contains "2016-01-01 00:00:00"
First row, last cell contains ""
```

because each line ends with a `;`. This empty 'cell' can trivially be removed during reading (ideally), or afterwards (as we still have it in memory):

```
data = [row[:-1] for row in data]
```

and then you get

```
First row, last cell contains "0"
```

and now you can use `data[row][column]` to address any cell that you want (in valid ranges only, of course).

<sup>Disclaimer: this is my very first look at the `csv` module. Some operations could possibly be done more efficiently. Practically all examples *verbatim* from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which proves it's always worth taking a look there **first**.</sup>

Comment: Wow man, these instructions give me a massive boost in this excersise. Thank you very much for your time and the help.
Because in this exersise, I work with few csv files; I changed
`filename = str(input("Give the file name: "))
with open(filename) as csvfile:`

Comment: Also a question; why do you start some of the prints with f' ? 
Is it possible to print the date times as in the file? Atm it prints 2016-01-01, but I'd like it to be 1.1.2016 (d.m.yr)

Comment: @Daniel: those are called [tag:f-string] – click that link for Stack Overflow results, or look it up in your favourite documentation. The "dates" are printed as such because they are not *dates* but just the exact *text* as they appear in your file.

Comment: In the file the texts are in a format of: "1.1.2016" (check the screencapture in the OP). When I print them, the format changes.

Comment: @Daniel: well all I know is that they are like this in your sample file, and I did not do anything to them. Sounds like you have a new question there.